# Atom editor 1.60 "Editor is not responding" at launch

Tags: atom

Since today, I can't open Atom Editor (my main work tool) on Ubuntu 20.04.

When it launch, it shows the code I was working on but can't open totally, and then I get the "Editor is not responding" error message :

[image]

I rebooted my computer and uninstalled/reinstalled Atom, with no result.

I tried `atom --clear-window-state` and removing the `~/atom` folder, no result.

So I'm thinking another library is faulty, but I don´t know which one ? Maybe I could downgrade Atom ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it working by removing the ~/.atom folder (then losing all the local config and cache), then rebooting my computer and finally launching Atom. Black magic sometime works.